# PyCharm warns me to create an object for a classmethod made by classmethod function

Tags: python, object, pycharm, self, class-method

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

> If a class method is called for a derived class, the derived class object is passed as the implied first argument.

So we can conclude that we don't need to create an object using class method function . But I don't know why PyCharm gives me this warning, while it executes the code with no problem at all.

This is the code:

```
class Fruit:
    def sayhi(self):
        print("Hi, I'm a fruit")


Fruit.sayhi = classmethod(Fruit.sayhi)
Fruit.sayhi()enter code here
```

And this is the warning

> Parameter self unfilled

[image: Parameter self unfilled !]

Comment: Use the classmethod function as a *decorator*, that might help PyCharm figure out what you're doing. Note also that the convention for a class method's first parameter is `cls`, not `self`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe; Thanks, It worked Pretty well, but could you tell me why it does not work with classmethod function?

Comment: I'd guess you've just found a limitation of the introspection and interpretation that PyCharm's doing to figure out what your code represents. The method is initially defined as an *instance* method, and only turned into a class method after the class is defined; evidently this doesn't update PyCharm's model of what the class contains.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what a technical explanation, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PyCharm gives you these warnings, it determines how the `sayhi` function works by looking at the class definition. According to your class definition, `sayhi` requires an argument `self` that you have not filled.  On line 6 you have re-assigned `sayhi` as a classmethod, however, as far as PyCharm is concerned, this is outside of the class definition so it is the "anything goes" territory and it won't bother trying to make assumptions based on what that code does.  If you want PyCharm to know that `sayhi` is a class method, you should specify that in the class definiton. For example, by using classmethod as a decorator

```
class Fruit:
    @classmethod
    def sayhi(self):
        print("Hi, im a fruit")
        
        
Fruit.sayhi()
```

[image]

No warning!

Comment: [in Dataflair in 11th number](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-built-in-functions/), It says " we call it like we would call any static method in python without an object.", so we need no object to be created to fill the self argument. ! So why would i need to fill self ?

Comment: As stated, PyCharm is giving you warnings based on the class definition only, meaning the code that falls indented to the `class Fruit:`.  the `classmethod` call on your line 6 in not considered at all when this warning is given.  You are calling `Fruit.sayhi`, and according to the original class definition you gave, that method requires an argument called self.  Remember, nothing about the code is wrong, its just PyCharm's understanding of the code is incorrect due to where the `classmethod` call was specified

Comment: So The class definition is considered when inspecting... Got it.

Comment: I believe that is correct. Anything outside of the class definition could be doing things that are far too difficult, or impossible for PyCharm to account for, so in general it won't consider it.  Think about it, its even possible that a completely separate file could be deleting, changing, replacing the methods of your class.  Or it could be changing the method based on a runtime condition that PyCharm couldn't possibly know the outcome of